# Write XLSX file with comments using js-xlsx

Tags: javascript, excel, xlsx, js-xlsx

Is it possible to insert some cell comments when we write a XLSX file with `js-xlsx` ?
When I read a file containing some cell comments, they appear when I read the file:

```
> var wb = XLSX.readFile("Book1comments.xlsx")                                                      
undefined                                                                                           
> wb.Sheets.Sheet1.A1.c                                                                             
[ { a: 'StÃ©phane Laurent',                                                                         
    t: 'Stéphane Laurent:\r\nhello',                                                                
    r: '<r><rPr><b/><sz val="9"/><color indexed="81"/><rFont val="Tahoma"/><charset val="1"/></rPr><
t>StÃ©phane Laurent:</t></r><r><rPr><sz val="9"/><color indexed="81"/><rFont val="Tahoma"/><charset 
val="1"/></rPr><t xml:space="preserve">\r\nhello</t></r>',                                          
    h: '<span style="font-weight: bold;">StÃ©phane Laurent:</span><span style=""><br/>hello</span>' 
} ]
```

Now, when I write this JSON workbook to a XLSX file:

```
XLSX.writeFile(wb, "Book1comments_rewritten.xlsx")
```

then there are no comments anymore in the created file.

**PS:** I tried to remove the strange characters in *StÃ©phane*, but this still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

As of 0.8.1 this is not possible, because one can see that every function related to writing the comments is empty in [xlsx.js](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/blob/2a756fffccc30bf6871d7f04ede61a6fef160555/xlsx.js#L8470):

```
function write_comments_xml(data, opts) { }
function write_comments_bin(data, opts) { }
/*
function write_cmnt(data, name, opts) {
    return (name.substr(-4)===".bin" ? write_comments_bin : write_comments_xml)(data, opts);
}
*/
```

Comment: It looks like this is available now: https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/commit/3a310bd3a7e17fb8501519b97ee36e44deb9aaa4